# Why is my else/if statement not working right in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm doing a project on codecademy, and one of the bits of code I have to write looks like this:

```
const calculateSleepDebt = () => {
const actualSleepHours = getActualSleepHours();
const idealSleepHours = getIdealSleepHours();
if (actualSleepHours === idealSleepHours) {
console.log('You got the perfect amount of sleep!');
} else if (actualSleepHours > idealSleepHours) {
console.log('You got too much sleep!');
} else (actualSleepHours < idealSleepHours) {
console.log('You did not get enough sleep!');
}
};
```

I get an "unexpected token" error message.

The code is supposed to take the values of the getActualSleepHours and getIdealSleepHours functions/variables, compare them, and log the correct statement.

While trouble shooting, I found that deleting the curly brackets around the else statement removes the error message, and logs the else if statement, the else statement, and an 'undefined'. I don't know if that is relevant as I'm new to this.

I tried turning it into a switch statement, like:

```
switch {
case (actualSleepHours === idealSleepHours) :
console.log('yadda yadda');
break;
```

but no luck either.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Review the syntax of [`if`…`else`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). Why did you put a condition after `else`? The [`switch`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) syntax is also wrong.

Comment: Removing the curly brackets will treat `(actualSleepHours < idealSleepHours)` as what needs to happen when the other conditions aren't met. _Not_ the condition of the `else`. The `{ ... }` after it will be treated as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) that is completely unrelated to the preceding `if`/`else if`/`else`. As Sebastian indicated, an `else` can't have a condition. It matches anything else that isn't matched by the conditions of the preceding `if`/`else if`'s.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your "else" have an arguments, but this is not right

```
const calculateSleepDebt = () => {
    const actualSleepHours = getActualSleepHours()
    const idealSleepHours = getIdealSleepHours()
    if (actualSleepHours === idealSleepHours) {
    console.log('You got the perfect amount of sleep!')
    } 
    else if (actualSleepHours > idealSleepHours) {
    console.log('You got too much sleep!')
    } 
    else{
    console.log('You did not get enough sleep!')
    }
    };
```

Try this! Sorry for my english <3

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! Do you have any idea why I'm still getting an 'undefined' after the correct statement?

Comment: I just checked your code and all conditions are met. Most likely your mistake is that the first two functions do not give values ​​for variables.

https://imgur.com/1cp5wl0